# Get pages and iMovies free

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac, applications, iwork

I got macbook pro late 2013 and normally `Pages` and `iMovies` they are free for mac after 2013 but when I got to app store I can't get them for free.
Any help here or how to get them free ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the app store in the purchased section to see if the apps are there, normally if you're using a brand new mac you should be able to find them there. If you bought a second hand mac I don't think you'll be able to get them for free (legally).

There is something i tried a long time ago i'm not sure it's still working, you need to download the [iWork ’09 trial](http://appldnld.apple.com.edgesuite.net/content.info.apple.com/iWork/Trial/2Z693-6764.01022009.awq23/iWork09Trial.dmg) Install it, open all of the apps (pages,numbers and keynote), quit the apps, launch the appstore and then update them.

I have no idea how to get iMovies for free.

Comment: Judging by the purchase date on my iMovies, I got mine free with a new iPhone, which allowed me to download for Mac too.